# Comparing two linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am new to programming.

I know there is a lot of better and nicer approach than mine to compare two linked-list. But, as I am new I would like to fix my code and get a sense of where I make the mistake.

What I am trying to do is loop through `both of the linkedlist` and compare each node at the same time.

Compare two linked lists A and B => Return 1 if they are identical and 0 if they are not.

I would genuinely appreciate your help in advance.

```
int CompareLists(Node headA, Node headB) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    Node tmpA = headA;
    Node tmpB = headB;

    if(tmpB.next != null && tmpA.next == null) return 0;

    while(tmpA.next != null) {

        if(tmpB.next == null) return 0;

        while(tmpB.next != null) {

            if (i == j) {

                if (tmpA.data != tmpB.data) return 0;

            } else {
                break;
            }
            tmpB = tmpB.next;

            j++;



        }   

        i++;

        tmpA = tmpA.next;

    }

    if(tmpA.data != tmpB.data) return 0;
    else return 1;

}
```

Comment: You should not have an inner while loop -> this implies that you're looping over every node in the second list for each node in the first. Instead, you should rely on the `if(tmpB.next == null)` condition you've already established.

Comment: `i` and `j` are not needed at all.

Comment: Also consider using `boolean` as the return type for your method for memory efficiency

Comment: @Welbog actually I like your comment idk if here I can like a comment or not. That is a good way to approach it but that would not still solve the actual problem. but having one loop for both linked-list is good 

Comment: @kabanus the only reason I use `i` and `j` is because I want to make sure always compare the same item in the same position. Do you think it's redundant?

Comment: @vatbub that is a valid point ☺️, but fixing the Algorithm is more in priority ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your code. Your general idea was good, but you did add some complications.

1. The two indices were unnecessary as you always keep your lists aligned (when B goes forward, you break if everything is OK and then A also goes forward). Which brings me to:
2. You did not need an inner while and break, just an if to check the current node
3. The one thing you did forget though - when `tmpA.next` is NULL you have not compared the current data of A and B - so you need to do one last check after the loop.

Here is a cleaned version:

```
int CompareLists(Node headA, Node headB) {    
    Node tmpA = headA;
    Node tmpB = headB;

    if(tmpB.next != null && tmpA.next == null) return 0;

    while(tmpA.next != null) {    
        if(tmpB.next == null || tmpA.data != tmpB.data) return 0;

        tmpB = tmpB.next;
        tmpA = tmpA.next;  
    }

    //Added:
    if(tmpB.next != null || tmpA.data != tmpB.data)  return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Of course, you don't have to work on `next` all the time. You can just test for `tmpA/tmpB == null` etc., to save some more space - I'll leave it for your consideration.

The final nit-pick, as pointed out by @vatbub in the comments, try and use the most appropriate types - returning a Boolean is what you actually want here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes apparently seems like I am overthinking stuff much more than I should :)

Comment: @JamieJamier Yup, that's common when starting to program. Your logic was good, so work on organizing your thoughts prior to actually coding.

Comment: @JamieJamier, it's called refactoring. A lot of code I write is far too overthought and includes a lot of stuff that isn't needed, but gets the job done. Then I refactor and end up with code like this. The only thing I would do is check the size of each of the linked lists if you've handled that within them. If they are different there's no need to go through the rest of the code. But since this appears to be a custom linked list it's likely you don't have the size and would have to iterate each of them to find it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It gets better with practice

```
int CompareLists(Node a, Node b) {
    while(a!=null && b!=null && a.data == b.data) {
        a=a.next;
        b=b.next;
    }
    return (a==null && b==null ? 1: 0);
}
```

Comment: I wish I could use arrow up, but as  I am beginner I can't but thumbs up Matt